# Coger valor de un campo de la base de datos estando en otro "id"?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

quiero mostrar en un menú la categorías, y subcategorias con un desplegable.
(En la imagen esta mal, deveria aparecer **Con motor** y dentro **Diesel** y **Gasolina**)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con  estos valores en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La 1º parte del **if** hace su función, pero al llegar a la segunda parte nose como hacer para que me imprima el nombre del **id_padre**.

El objetivo es clicar en Con motor y que aparezcan las subcategorias.

```
        if ($row["id_padre"]==NULL){?>
          <a class="list-group-item" data-remote="true" href="#" id="<?php  echo $row["id"]; ?>" style="padding-left: 25px;">
            <span class="fa <?php echo $row['icon']; ?> fa-lg fa-fw"></span>
            <span style="margin-left: 25px;"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></span>
          </a> <?php
        }
        else{ ?>
          <a class="list-group-item" data-remote="true" href="#" id="<?php  echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="<?php  echo $row['id_padre']; ?>" style="padding-left: 25px;">
            <span class="fa fa <?php echo $row['icon']; ?> fa-lg fa-fw"></span>
            <span style="margin-left: 25px;"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></span>
            <span class="menu-ico-collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
          </a>

          <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="<?php  echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-item" data-parent="#" style="padding-left: 78px;"><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></a>
          </div> <?php
        }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una subconsulta a la misma tabla con la referencia externa, prueba esto

```
SELECT 
  categorias.id_padre AS padre,
  categorias.*, 
  (SELECT nombre FROM categorias WHERE id = padre ) AS nombre_padre
FROM categorias
```